# How to concatenate image name with date in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to store image name with date in folder and  database.

For example image name is `Desert.png`

I want to store in database and folder like this: `2016-08-29Desert.png`

```
 $this->upload->do_upload(date('Y-d-m).'photo');
```

This code does not save image in folder and database.

How to solve this in CodeIgniter

Comment: [`do_upload()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload) has absolutely no reference to any interaction with a database. This is very much an incomplete question.

Comment: Check config array that need to be set with parameters for uploading. There you can set desired name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to generate a random string along with the name of the file.  But from what you asked, the code below should be enough.

```
$this->load->library('upload');

$imagePath = './images/';       

if(!file_exists($imagePath))
   mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);

$name_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$name_full  = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name_parts['filename']);
$file_name  = date('Y-m-d') . '-' . $name_full;

$config['upload_path']      = $imagePath;
$config['file_name']        = $file_name;
$config['allowed_types']    = 'png|bmp|jpg';
$config['max_size']         = '1024'; // 1MB~
$config['overwrite']        = FALSE;

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('photo') == FALSE)
   return;
```